# How to efficiently cluster a dataframe column of numpy arrays

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe, dask-ml

I started to look into Dask as I need to handle a large dataset that doesn't fit in RAM.

The data are saved in parquet-files as dataframes with a column "coordinates" that contains NumPy arrays of shape 2 -- i.e. the dtype of the column is "object", something like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"coordinates": [np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4])]})
>>> df
  coordinates
0      [1, 2]
1      [3, 4]
>>> df.dtypes
coordinates    object
```

Now, I want to find clusters in these coordinates using dask_ml.cluster.KMeans.

It looks like this:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask_ml.cluster import KMeans

df = dd.read_parquet("*.parquet")
arr = df["coordinates"].to_dask_array(lengths=True)

kmeans = KMeans()
kmeans.fit(arr)

print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
```

Sadly, the fit function can't handle the array:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

The problem seems to be that "arr" is an array of arrays identified as objects `array([array([...], dtype=float32), ...], dtype=object)` instead of a ndarray `array([[...], ...], dtype=float32)`, so I have to convert df["coordinates"] to an array by stacking

```
arr = da.stack(df["descriptors"].to_dask_array(lengths=True))
```

But it seems that this tries to create arr by sequential operation in memory (i.e. using a single core) and is thus not feasible.

NB: I also tried decorating `da.stack` by `delayed` hoping this would allow Dask to delay and distribute the needed operations until kmeans.fit is called, but this throws an error also. Since I'm very new to Dask and its concepts, this might also not be what delayed is actually used for.

What would be the Dask-way to handle this problem? How can I transform my `df["coordinates"]` into an array that does not completely reside in memory but can be fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up top, you should know that you shouldn't do this in *pandas*, not just dask. dask.dataframe is built on pandas, and pandas is built on numpy. Numpy can hold arrays of fixed-width strongly typed numerical data (e.g. float64, int16, etc) or objects. Fixed-type arrays occupy contiguous blocks of memory and are very fast to work with; on the other hand, object arrays necessitate using arrays of pointers to the object addresses and are much slower. So it is much better practice to use two columns of np.float data than a single object column, with each cell pointing to a numpy array holding two np.floats.

Now, for dask.dataframe. Because dask depends on scheduling and allocating memory for partitions *before the calculations reveal the results*, it does not have even as much support object-type columns as pandas. You can read in a parquet file laid out as you have it, but things may break later on as you've discovered.

Good news is you can easily map an operation to expand the column into multiple fixed-type columns using [`dask.dataframe.map_partitions`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions.html):

```py
coord_df = df["coordinates"].map_partitions(
    lambda sub: pd.DataFrame(
        np.vstack(sub), columns=["x", "y"], index=sub.index
    ),
    meta=[("x", np.float64), ("y", np.float64)],
)
arr = coord_df.to_dask_array(lengths=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I chose the dataframe format that way because I actually have related data in columns "coordinates", "features", etc. where each column holds high dimensional vectors. Enumerating the vector dimensions in the dataframe column names, like "feature_0", ..., "feature_128", didn't seem to be a good solution. MultiIndexing ("features", 0), ..., ("features", 128) gave me problems, too, with the parquet files. I guess then that dataframes are not really suited for my problem.

Comment: have you considered [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/), which supports labeled high-dimensional data structures natively? but if you need a dataframe-like format, especially for use with ML tools, I'd push back and say - what's wrong with `feaure_128`? this isn't any more cumbersome than `df["feature"].str[128]` or however you're referencing each feature, but it actually corresponds to the optimal memory layout for good pandas+dask.dataframe performance. I'd stress that you will see significant performance improvements if you store your data in fixed-type arrays rather than object arrays.

Comment: I didn't know about xarray and will look into it. And actually you are right that naming the columns "feature_128" etc. is not really a problem. Just made me -- irrationally -- feel uneasy. Though I already went that route for the creation of a new dataset. Thanks again.